# Highest and lowest value from table sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm getting all my column details like below:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table1'
    AND DATA_TYPE IN ('int','decimal','numeric')
```

my table structure is like below:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table1](
[col1] int not NULL,
[col2] [numeric](7, 0) NULL,
[col3] [varchar](30) NULL,
[col4] [varchar](8) NULL,
[col5] [varchar](2) NULL,
[col6] [varchar](8) NULL,
[col7] [varchar](3) NULL,
[col8] [varchar](7) NULL,
[col9] [varchar](5) NULL,
[col10] [varchar](8) NULL,
[col11] [numeric](7, 0) NULL,
[col12] [numeric](7, 3) NULL,
[col13] [numeric](7, 2) NULL,
[col14] [decimal](7, 2) NULL,
[col15] [varchar](1) NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Here is few example values when I'm querying table1

```
 col1   col2     col11      col12       col13      col14
 ------------------------------------------------------------
 1      10.0      80.00      10.000      12.00      90.00
 2      70.0      10.00      97.960      14.00      10.00
 3      30.00     12.00      14.000      115.00     11.00
 4      40.00     11.00      15.000      15.80      12.00
```

I wanted my result to be like:

```
 for max:

Table_name   max_col_name     max_col_value     max_col_value_length
---------------------------------------------------------------------
 table1       col3               115.00               6


 for min value:

Table_name   min_col_name     min_col_value     min_col_value_length
---------------------------------------------------------------------
 table1       col1               1                   1
```

How can I acheive this?

Comment: I think you will need some dynamic SQL here, since the queries themselves which find the min/max values must be generated on the fly.

Comment: What are you trying to solve? Because a task like that might be better handled in a code layer outside SQL as it's not really a relational operation?

Comment: I have tables of more than 20Millon records each and instead of searching and finding one by one I want some query to give me result as in the question.

Comment: You need the min and max whatever column it is?

Comment: Yes. However, I think, It's OK to skip "col1 ", that is an identity column. Also, my table other columns have Negative values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to get the desired result. If the column names are dynamic then you can easily convert the below code into dynamic sql.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table1](
[col1] int not NULL,
[col2] [numeric](7, 0) NULL,
[col3] [varchar](30) NULL,
[col4] [varchar](8) NULL,
[col5] [varchar](2) NULL,
[col6] [varchar](8) NULL,
[col7] [varchar](3) NULL,
[col8] [varchar](7) NULL,
[col9] [varchar](5) NULL,
[col10] [varchar](8) NULL,
[col11] [numeric](7, 0) NULL,
[col12] [numeric](7, 3) NULL,
[col13] [numeric](7, 2) NULL,
[col14] [decimal](7, 2) NULL,
[col15] [varchar](1) NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

insert into  table1 (col1,col2,col11,col12,col13,col14)  values 
(1,      10.0  ,    80.00,      10.000  ,    12.00    ,  90.00),
(2,     70.0  ,    10.00  ,    97.960    ,  14.00     , 10.00),
(3,      30.00,     12.00  ,    14.000    ,  115.00   ,  11.00),
(4,      40.00,     11.00   ,   15.000     , 15.80    ,  12.00)  

declare @sql varchar(max)
declare @col varchar(max)=''
select @col=@col+ COLUMN_NAME +', ' FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table1'
    AND DATA_TYPE IN ('int','decimal','numeric')

SELECT ColumnName,ColumnValue 
into #TableMax
from (select cast(max(col1) as numeric(7,3))C1, CAST(max(col2) as numeric(7,3))C2, 
                                           cast(max(col11) as numeric(7,3))C11, CAST(max(col12) as numeric(7,3))C12, 
                                           CAST(max(col13) as numeric(7,3))C13, CAST(Max(col14) as numeric(7,3))C14

from table1) T
 Unpivot(ColumnValue For ColumnName IN (C1,C2,C11,C12,C13,C14)) AS H

SELECT ColumnName,ColumnValue 
into #TableMin
from (select cast(Min(col1) as numeric(7,3))C1, CAST(Min(col2) as numeric(7,3))C2, 
                                           cast(Min(col11) as numeric(7,3))C11, CAST(Min(col12) as numeric(7,3))C12, 
                                           CAST(Min(col13) as numeric(7,3))C13, CAST(Min(col14) as numeric(7,3))C14

from table1) T
 Unpivot(ColumnValue For ColumnName IN (C1,C2,C11,C12,C13,C14)) AS H

select top 1 columnname max_columnname,columnvalue max_columnvalue,len(columnvalue)max_col_value_length from  #TableMax order  by columnvalue desc
select top 1 columnname min_columnname,columnvalue min_columnvalue,len(columnvalue)min_col_value_length from  #TableMin order  by columnvalue 
drop table table1
drop table #TableMax
drop table #TableMin
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
DECLARE @TB TABLE(col1 int, col2 decimal(10,2), col11 decimal(10,3), col12 decimal(10,2),col13 decimal(10,2),col14 decimal(10,2))
insert into @tb
select  1 ,     10.0   ,   80.00   ,   10.000  ,    12.00  ,    90.00 union all
select   2 ,     70.0   ,   10.00  ,    97.960  ,    14.00  ,    10.00 union all
select   3 ,     30.00  ,   12.00  ,    14.000  ,    115.00 ,    11.00 union all
select   4  ,    40.00  ,   11.00  ,    15.000 ,     15.80  ,    12.00





select 'table1' as Table_Name,b.column_name as max_col_name, cast(a.max_col as decimal(10,2)) as max_col_value , len(cast(a.max_col as decimal(10,2))) as  max_col_value_length from
(select max(max_col1) as max_col from
(select max(col1) as max_col1,'col1' as column_name from @tb union all
select max(col2) as max_col2,'col2' from @tb union all
select max(col11)as max_col11,'col11'  from @tb union all
select max(col12)as max_col12,'col12' from @tb union all
select max(col13)as max_col13,'col13' from @tb union all
select max(col14)as max_col14,'col14' from @tb) as a) as a

left join

(select max(max_col1) as max_col,column_name from
(select max(col1) as max_col1,'col1' as column_name from @tb union all
select max(col2) as max_col2,'col2' from @tb union all
select max(col11)as max_col11,'col11'  from @tb union all
select max(col12)as max_col12,'col12' from @tb union all
select max(col13)as max_col13,'col13' from @tb union all
select max(col14)as max_col14,'col14' from @tb) as a group by column_name) as b
on a.max_col = b.max_col








select 'table1' as Table_Name,b.column_name as min_col_name, cast(a.min_col as integer) as min_col_value , len(cast(a.min_col as integer)) min_col_value_length from
(select min(min_col1) as min_col from
(select min(col1) as min_col1,'col1' as column_name from @tb union all
select min(col2) as min_col2,'col2' from @tb union all
select min(col11)as min_col11,'col11'  from @tb union all
select min(col12)as min_col12,'col12' from @tb union all
select min(col13)as min_col13,'col13' from @tb union all
select min(col14)as min_col14,'col14' from @tb) as a) as a

left join

(select min(min_col1) as min_col,column_name from
(select min(col1) as min_col1,'col1' as column_name from @tb union all
select min(col2) as min_col2,'col2' from @tb union all
select min(col11)as min_col11,'col11'  from @tb union all
select min(col12)as min_col12,'col12' from @tb union all
select min(col13)as min_col13,'col13' from @tb union all
select min(col14)as min_col14,'col14' from @tb) as a group by column_name) as b
on a.min_col = b.min_col
```

result for max:

```
table1  col13   115.00  6
```

result for min:

```
table1  col1    1   1
```

Comment: Thanks. But, I have tables where the column count  varies between 10 - 50. That is some table has 10 columns and some has 50. Can cols be dynamic?

Comment: It's all yours, if you have a lot of columns.. you can edit that answer above and add other column you want. the important is you have already a guide on how to do it.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can achieve this with two steps, first you search max or min value of each column then unpivot it (rotate the table so the column will become row and row become column) to find the overall max or min value.

This query will find max value

```
 WITH cte1 AS (SELECT 'table1' AS Table_name 
                      ,max_col_name
                      ,max_col_value
                      ,LEN(max_col_value) AS max_col_value_length 
               FROM
                   (SELECT col2,col3,col4 
                     FROM 
                     (SELECT MAX(col2) AS col2 
                            ,MAX(col3) AS col3
                            ,MAX(col4) AS col4 FROM table1) x) y
                    UNPIVOT
                    (Nilai FOR max_col_name IN (col2,col3,col4)) unpvt) 

SELECT * FROM cte
WHERE max_col_value = (SELECT MAX(max_col_value) FROM cte)
```

To find Min value just change all Max with Min